# service not starting in springboot

Tags: testing, spring-boot, rest-assured

I am writing my tests using rest-assured and Spring Boot. Unfortunatly the service is not starting in the tests. This is my code:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ServiceApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8083")
@Slf4j
public class ServicePingIT {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;
    private String Uri = "/service/ping";
    private String validation = "Service is up and running...";

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssured.port = port;
        RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost";
    }

    @Test
    public void validatePingBody() {
        log.info("");
        validateREsponse(Uri, validation);
    }
```

What is wrong with my test setup that the service is not starting? In the logs I do see that Tomcat starts at the port but fails with this error:

```
ERROR 7432 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/service]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Service not starting using Spring-boot during integration tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721194/service-not-starting-using-spring-boot-during-integration-tests)

Comment: I'd expect there to be more information in the logs about the start failure of the child component. Is there anything in the logs before the output that you've included above?